# Access WPF MediaElement Sound Stream form NAudio

Tags: naudio

I am new to using NAudio so sorry if my question sounds naive.

My project is to play a video file using WPF MediaElement control then access the audio stream of the played video (using NAudio) to represent the audio track of the video while being played (waveform, etc.).

I looked into how to let the NAudio access the audio track of a video file in MediaElement control   but could not find a resource..

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: What did you try ? Can you show some code ?

Comment: I'm afraid this is not a feature of NAudio, and something that the WPF Media Element does not permit in any case. You'd need to go lower-level to get directly to the sound-track of the video. Possibly using WASAPI loopback recording might be good enough for your needs instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to try the preview release of NAudio 1.7 ([available on NuGet](https://nuget.org/packages/NAudio)) it can now read soundtracks out of video files using Media Foundation. Use the `MediaFoundationReader` class. Here's how you would save the soundtrack to a WAV file:

```
using (var reader = new MediaFoundationReader("mymovie.m4v"))
{
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(reader, "soundtrack.wav");
}
```

Obviously for waveform drawing you would not need to make a WAV file. Just look at the sample values to get peaks for a waveform renderer.

Note that Media Foundation is only supported on Windows Vista and above.